# Retrieving raw private key from x509 file

Tags: php, openssl

I need to obtain the raw private key from my x509 pem file as a variable. How do I do it? I tried referencing the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955446/retrieving-raw-private-key-from-openssl-pkey-get-private), but it returns a NULL value for me.

Here is my code:

```
define("APP_SIGNATURE_CERT_PRIVATE_KEY", "C://demo/ssl/testapp_private.pem");
$privateKeyContent = APP_SIGNATURE_CERT_PRIVATE_KEY;

$fp = fopen($privateKeyContent, "r");
$privateKey= fread($fp, 8192);

var_dump($privateKey); //Prints the entire key content

openssl_pkey_export($privateKey, $pkeyout); 

var_dump ($pkeyout); //Prints NULL

$privateKeyResource = openssl_pkey_get_private($privateKey);

var_dump ($privateKeyResource) // Prints resource(18) of type (OpenSSL key)
```

---

I want to get the raw private key like below (sample).

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAzuhc4J08EiayUSpIQ9MG6FM5JwYm1d0UIaAZ9h2QV4r897Oo
GxvxaQ/ceIY7Sdrpc6kWAF+cemKfA84WX6T+LgiimfZnSIDhF1xHFk2Yluc8cyqq 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 
eIbY59CMiPitH0Q0N6UkgwKBgQCktsHJ48zCKGu8X3I11DAxYy6kl1mPgt3Zhwpm 
o+cMb2B2QEFsGLar0vxztA6IUUQnZp4YolAmSBX6Y0qLXgyFUDzcvxygKABmHcCV 
rogsUatkUcvUCSFa41xx21A8OxKTLz2iRHEhsKo3aR1FQW4nowTIlv0RIrXqnZ8F 
aWr5pwKBgGngeK3PyoXvOZNZ5f9r3i4C3d7UHz9Aiwn2Ulh138dp1AW8d4a9AiTZ 
RBd9pQGsIsSzhPkTZ65Mx+R6X+v/xfnFjnShronfeNdkpkgACbgQvJTDbg8Asu9x 
ifwaEKu8+t1MqrmPh5vKY6Fhl2DdPkk2evp6eG1t1IO6pAkYb8L5

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

This is my entire pem file.
But I have removed the key and certificate details.

```
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 01 00 00 00 
    friendlyName: 4|77|128|0|b5n6B+idS7CemwyB8Vax+A==
    Microsoft CSP Name: Entrust Enhanced Cryptographic Provider
Key Attributes
    X509v3 Key Usage: 80 
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
<key content here>
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 01 00 00 00 
    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.3.32774: 00 
    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.3.92: 00 08 00 00 
    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.3.32769: 00 00 00 00 
    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.3.32772: 00 00 00 00 
    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.3.32773: 01 00 00 00 1D 00 00 00 23 01 00 00 
    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.3.20: 33 E5 CE 92 3B 6A 7A 04 16 EC 51 38 35 DF 8B 57 12 45 EB EA 
    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.3.32782: 56 00 65 00 72 00 69 00 66 00 69 00 63 00 61 00 74 00 69 00 6F 00 6E 00 00 00 
friendlyName: AAA's Verification Certificate
    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.3.32768: 43 00 4E 00 3D 00 45 00 6E 00 64 00 20 00 55 00 73 00 65 00 72 00 20 00 50 00 6F 00 6C 00 69 00 63 00 79 00 2C 00 20 00 4F 00 55 00 3D 00 4E 00 65 00 74 00 72 00 75 00 73 00 74 00 20 00 43 00 41 00 31 00 2C 00 20 00 4F 00 3D 00 4E 00 65 00 74 00 72 00 75 00 73 00 74 00 20 00 43 00 65 00 72 00 74 00 69 00 66 00 69 00 63 00 61 00 74 00 65 00 20 00 41 00 75 00 74 00 68 00 6F 00 72 00 69 00 74 00 79 00 20 00 31 00 2C 00 20 00 43 00 3D 00 53 00 47 00 00 00 
    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.3.32775: 43 00 4E 00 3D 00 56 00 65 00 72 00 69 00 66 00 69 00 63 00 61 00 74 00 69 00 6F 00 6E 00 20 00 45 00 78 00 70 00 6F 00 72 00 74 00 20 00 50 00 6F 00 6C 00 69 00 63 00 79 00 2C 00 20 00 4F 00 55 00 3D 00 4E 00 65 00 74 00 72 00 75 00 73 00 74 00 20 00 43 00 41 00 31 00 2C 00 20 00 4F 00 3D 00 4E 00 65 00 74 00 72 00 75 00 73 00 74 00 20 00 43 00 65 00 72 00 74 00 69 00 66 00 69 00 63 00 61 00 74 00 65 00 20 00 41 00 75 00 74 00 68 00 6F 00 72 00 69 00 74 00 79 00 20 00 31 00 2C 00 20 00 43 00 3D 00 53 00 47 00 00 00 
    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.3.32780: 30 82 0B 72 30 82 01 A1 02 01 01 A4 4F 30 4D 31 0B 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 53 47 31 28 30 26 06 03 55 04 0A 13 1F 4E 65 74 72 75 73 74 20 43 65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61 74 65 20 41 75 74 68 6F 72 69 74 79 20 31 31 14 30 12 06 03 55 04 0B 13 0B 4E 65 74 72 75 73 74 20 43 41 31 A4 81 9F 30 81 9C 31 0B 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 53 47 31 28 30 26 06 03 55 04 0A 13 1F 4E 65 74 72 75 73 74 20 43 65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61 74 65 20 41 75 74 68 6F 72 69 74 79 20 31 31 1D 30 1B 06 03 55 04 0B 13 14 4E 65 74 72 75 73 74 20 43 41 31 20 28 53 65 72 76 65 72 29 31 1C 30 1A 06 03 55 04 0B 13 13 4D 69 6E 69 73 74 72 79 20 6F 66 20 46 69 6E 61 6E 63 65 31 11 30 0F 06 03 55 04 0B 13 08 53 69 6E 67 50 61 73 73 31 13 30 11 06 03 55 04 03 13 0A 73 74 67 2D 6D 79 69 6E 66 6F A0 11 18 0F 32 30 31 35 30 37 32 31 30 34 33 39 32 32 5A A1 0F 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 05 05 00 A2 16 04 14 61 89 F2 24 F6 E3 88 43 44 53 AD 5A 7B EB AC 54 69 F2 95 5D A3 02 04 00 A4 06 04 04 A3 D2 45 64 A5 12 04 10 B9 37 0D 4F 4B 7C D9 50 3B 42 98 45 0D 9B A2 8C A6 12 04 10 1F 34 56 CC 20 4A 6E B4 FB 3E 29 CC D8 06 4A AB A7 20 30 1E 0C 1C 45 6E 74 72 75 73 74 20 50 4B 49 58 2D 43 4D 50 20 73 65 72 76 65 72 20 76 35 2E 30 A8 17 30 15 30 13 06 09 60 86 48 01 86 FA 6B 32 13 03 06 06 7F E7 F8 7F C0 B6 82 04 6D 30 82 04 69 30 82 04 55 06 08 2B 06 01 05 05 07 04 01 30 82 04 47 30 82 03 2F A0 03 02 01 02 02 0C 40 EF 6E 3D 00 00 00 00 49 D1 E8 EC 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 05 05 00 30 4D 31 0B 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 53 47 31 28 30 26 06 03 55 04 0A 13 1F 4E 65 74 72 75 73 74 20 43 65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61 74 65 20 41 75 74 68 6F 72 69 74 79 20 31 31 14 30 12 06 03 55 04 0B 13 0B 4E 65 74 72 75 73 74 20 43 41 31 30 1E 17 0D 31 35 30 37 32 30 31 33 33 34 31 30 5A 17 0D 31 35 30 37 32 31 31 34 30 34 31 30 5A 30 4D 31 0B 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 53 47 31 28 30 26 06 03 55 04 0A 13 1F 4E 65 74 72 75 73 74 20 43 65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61 74 65 20 41 75 74 68 6F 72 69 74 79 20 31 31 14 30 12 06 03 55 04 0B 13 0B 4E 65 74 72 75 73 74 20 43 41 31 30 82 01 22 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01 05 00 03 82 01 0F 00 30 82 01 0A 02 82 01 01 00 C3 23 69 64 82 AA AE E3 C2 37 BA DA A5 C6 C8 CA 21 1B 71 B5 13 71 8E 57 9A 97 57 CB 18 DA D4 72 1F 34 0A E8 EC 2D 51 72 E9 0A 64 0F CC 5D EB A5 28 A5 CB 90 0B B8 E3 A1 02 AF 87 86 1B 08 33 69 C5 56 11 B4 0B 62 DC 37 B3 0F C8 56 CF 79 58 AB 99 78 58 9C 4F 25 42 EE 54 20 8D 17 EF 3F 2D 52 EB 33 3F 0A 86 A9 A3 EC 5B E1 6C BD 60 50 EA 50 BB 64 4E 83 D9 EF AA C5 1A 28 0D CA E0 EE 3B DE 93 13 AD 07 5A 71 6A A2 2E F8 B4 42 BA 5E EF E2 EA 07 B4 28 25 AD F6 35 A3 8B 0E EB 98 5D 1A 7B 24 50 DC 87 6C C9 02 88 B4 6B C1 7E 90 C8 0C 32 9E AF 38 24 05 DD 56 7A DF 17 57 2A DE 0D BE B1 F4 9A 12 AD 05 D1 9A 32 81 DE 50 CC 7D 1D A1 E9 3C 00 DB F9 2B 6C E8 49 D6 A3 FD FA 8F 87 42 11 14 A6 EB A9 DE D4 60 FD 0F FF 7F 01 FC FF 7C 00 F0 0B A8 D4 DF FA 85 E4 A3 7A 92 D1 8C 2C D7 41 02 03 01 00 01 A3 82 01 25 30 82 01 21 30 81 A8 06 03 55 1D 1F 04 81 A0 30 81 9D 30 64 A0 62 A0 60 A4 5E 30 5C 31 0B 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 53 47 31 28 30 26 06 03 55 04 0A 13 1F 4E 65 74 72 75 73 74 20 43 65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61 74 65 20 41 75 74 68 6F 72 69 74 79 20 31 31 14 30 12 06 03 55 04 0B 13 0B 4E 65 74 72 75 73 74 20 43 41 31 31 0D 30 0B 06 03 55 04 03 13 04 43 52 4C 31 30 35 A0 33 A0 31 86 2F 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 6E 65 74 72 75 73 74 63 6F 6E 6E 65 63 74 6F 72 2E 6E 65 74 72 75 73 74 2E 6E 65 74 2F 6E 65 74 72 75 73 74 2E 63 72 6C 30 0B 06 03 55 1D 0F 04 04 03 02 05 20 30 1F 06 03 55 1D 23 04 18 30 16 80 14 1D 44 89 B2 45 26 7F 6F 6B 92 C5 3A 7B 72 63 CA D2 70 2A DD 30 1D 06 03 55 1D 0E 04 16 04 14 7F BE AF 05 F4 3A D9 94 48 3A 02 A1 73 85 F5 00 98 10 52 D1 30 0C 06 03 55 1D 13 04 05 30 03 01 01 FF 30 19 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F6 7D 07 41 00 04 0C 30 0A 1B 04 56 38 2E 31 03 02 04 90 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 05 05 00 03 82 01 01 00 23 2C ED 68 3B B8 FF AB 6D B9 7B 08 C3 08 84 69 51 1A B4 5F 27 EF 0E 45 FE 9E 78 05 9B D8 7C FF 2A 70 DD DD 68 4A 5A 78 0D 80 93 6F 37 E8 1D 4D 82 7F 9E E7 EA 2B CC 54 52 41 3C 7E F2 C3 2A 0B B2 51 79 1F E2 46 40 2F B3 3C 84 19 8A 49 75 F3 B0 0F 68 0E 72 FC A5 88 79 5B 60 AE 4B 76 3E 20 12 4C EF CD 49 42 55 C4 D6 DA D3 2C 50 AA EA F0 72 8B 52 B9 9F D1 8F F6 E5 49 1F CA B6 AC F2 37 FC B8 C0 A3 60 9C 44 1D 3C 1A 25 01 09 77 29 09 3F 81 33 7E B2 94 81 E6 B9 A8 FA EB 93 B6 25 35 BB BC 8F 61 6E 20 F9 BA BF DC EC 37 04 A7 AA 24 0A 33 7A 9D 67 61 FE AB 87 31 4D 45 52 25 8E 76 CD 74 22 87 D7 81 1E 3F CE D9 F3 87 3C 1C 47 33 F6 59 91 31 79 FB FD 58 9D F8 48 E2 EA E8 6A BA B2 67 FE E7 8B B0 FE 93 62 52 42 76 EA F7 46 67 23 ED 54 3C 13 F9 B5 44 BC E5 AE F8 DF 8C 39 7D 30 0E 06 09 60 86 48 01 86 FA 6B 32 06 02 01 02 A0 82 01 05 03 82 01 01 00 74 8A 0D 34 EA 05 D7 F0 96 AC 92 FD AD B8 D9 BE 9D 1E 53 EC A6 F2 0E 7B B1 C5 69 F9 98 1E C9 4D D4 C7 4C F3 3D 53 A7 C3 78 53 25 DF 64 1B E1 B6 0C 01 32 4D 8C BB 21 9F 8D DB 1C 7B 52 37 3C 3D B6 2F D3 07 D2 AD 83 17 6C F8 8A 96 63 F1 07 75 B0 5E 25 09 43 F4 16 40 AC 4E 6A 17 24 FE E5 8D D5 77 51 15 37 02 14 E1 BA 89 E9 17 24 D9 6A 31 D2 EC A0 A1 99 25 54 DD 2F A7 A3 2B 02 7E F9 AB C9 52 89 1D 55 76 07 A2 C8 51 C3 44 4A A4 B5 16 30 44 C1 17 C6 BB 93 7A 19 07 73 14 1B 72 92 A0 6D 7E 14 AB 70 88 12 7F 20 28 99 15 1F E5 19 98 A7 69 17 8E D1 84 AC 8C 1A F4 85 4A 70 81 F4 95 17 92 C0 AE 1B 76 F7 47 28 8D FA D6 E0 3B 59 F6 87 4F 13 3C BE E5 96 F5 F4 4F 5A 5A 54 72 F1 A1 B6 0B A2 45 05 7C 42 2A A9 C4 27 D6 D4 02 8E 39 B3 1D EB F6 56 2B B6 1B 24 98 A0 CF 85 3A EE AD A1 82 04 4F 30 82 04 4B 30 82 04 47 30 82 03 2F A0 03 02 01 02 02 0C 59 6B CA 22 00 00 00 00 49 D1 E8 EB 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 05 05 00 30 4D 31 0B 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 53 47 31 28 30 26 06 03 55 04 0A 13 1F 4E 65 74 72 75 73 74 20 43 65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61 74 65 20 41 75 74 68 6F 72 69 74 79 20 31 31 14 30 12 06 03 55 04 0B 13 0B 4E 65 74 72 75 73 74 20 43 41 31 30 1E 17 0D 31 35 30 37 32 30 31 33 33 34 31 30 5A 17 0D 31 35 30 37 32 31 31 34 30 34 31 30 5A 30 4D 31 0B 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 53 47 31 28 30 26 06 03 55 04 0A 13 1F 4E 65 74 72 75 73 74 20 43 65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61 74 65 20 41 75 74 68 6F 72 69 74 79 20 31 31 14 30 12 06 03 55 04 0B 13 0B 4E 65 74 72 75 73 74 20 43 41 31 30 82 01 22 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01 05 00 03 82 01 0F 00 30 82 01 0A 02 82 01 01 00 BC 9B 79 8F 33 10 17 97 66 2C 77 BF 45 73 B7 C8 CC 16 F1 9E F2 42 C0 68 8A F8 E2 6F AC CE 74 9C C9 05 16 6E EB BD D4 5C C5 F8 75 7C 39 BF 5D 8B E1 0B 7F FF 38 EE BE C5 96 26 14 13 7B 88 BF AA 45 D1 93 23 31 60 99 04 66 10 9F 07 8D 3F 21 FE 58 5C 7F 63 70 EA 0F B3 32 2F D0 CC B9 CF 1A 95 D0 04 F1 49 CA 2E E7 94 92 F4 25 83 97 9A 5F 15 08 11 B9 D1 4E 68 0F 3B 66 CB 4B 02 E8 DF 44 7F 66 32 7A 88 4D 6B 56 66 4B DD D2 E5 04 1A B5 6E 6B 7D 3E 02 3F FF C3 F3 0C 3C 53 81 4E 77 FD 92 9B B6 FD BB 82 47 8E 0C A6 81 61 62 5E 75 CE 6C 4E 01 56 2C 9E 67 6C 7B A5 6A 4E B2 3E BC FD A4 A0 45 6D A0 77 E6 10 07 59 3D 7C 28 A3 ED 73 40 C3 AB B7 45 5B A2 A4 50 B3 88 69 C7 DF EB 29 A1 27 B4 F2 40 B8 B4 6D 5D EE ED B0 F4 0C E4 E2 E0 06 4F F4 F7 CE 34 BE 23 1A 82 3E 50 43 A9 3D 63 02 03 01 00 01 A3 82 01 25 30 82 01 21 30 81 A8 06 03 55 1D 1F 04 81 A0 30 81 9D 30 64 A0 62 A0 60 A4 5E 30 5C 31 0B 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 53 47 31 28 30 26 06 03 55 04 0A 13 1F 4E 65 74 72 75 73 74 20 43 65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61 74 65 20 41 75 74 68 6F 72 69 74 79 20 31 31 14 30 12 06 03 55 04 0B 13 0B 4E 65 74 72 75 73 74 20 43 41 31 31 0D 30 0B 06 03 55 04 03 13 04 43 52 4C 31 30 35 A0 33 A0 31 86 2F 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 6E 65 74 72 75 73 74 63 6F 6E 6E 65 63 74 6F 72 2E 6E 65 74 72 75 73 74 2E 6E 65 74 2F 6E 65 74 72 75 73 74 2E 63 72 6C 30 0B 06 03 55 1D 0F 04 04 03 02 07 80 30 1F 06 03 55 1D 23 04 18 30 16 80 14 1D 44 89 B2 45 26 7F 6F 6B 92 C5 3A 7B 72 63 CA D2 70 2A DD 30 1D 06 03 55 1D 0E 04 16 04 14 61 89 F2 24 F6 E3 88 43 44 53 AD 5A 7B EB AC 54 69 F2 95 5D 30 0C 06 03 55 1D 13 04 05 30 03 01 01 FF 30 19 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F6 7D 07 41 00 04 0C 30 0A 1B 04 56 38 2E 31 03 02 04 90 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 05 05 00 03 82 01 01 00 4B 0F 63 74 6A AC 7D BD 3E C4 D8 B3 68 08 14 8D 9D D1 EB 38 9E DB C0 8D 8A 22 24 43 FF A5 F8 9D 8F AC 34 44 D9 6B E5 09 F1 A7 A5 8D A2 31 B4 B6 0B 8B F7 73 93 C2 C3 90 12 A7 40 D1 7E 83 05 5C D7 4D EE DA D7 47 89 00 FF E3 F7 C6 A4 1A F9 FC 43 59 66 15 C0 FE EA FF 9C F2 3A 00 ED 90 46 4E FA C1 56 2D A0 F3 E0 8E 8C 7E 55 5E 53 D2 72 3C 56 F5 A2 DE 64 7D 6F EC CC 0E 51 10 FD 54 1D FD F6 7F D1 FA 70 5F 1A AB 87 ED ED 4C 6A 60 84 0A 55 10 54 13 24 CA 3C EA F2 E4 14 64 72 F5 F9 A8 D1 82 6A 20 08 D3 80 60 91 7B 48 14 40 EB 7A DF ED 03 3A 40 EB 3A 97 2B FE FD 70 F2 1F F3 86 20 0D 03 3A 3E E2 21 A3 3F B8 38 DE 78 51 FF EA E9 19 A7 28 5A 88 18 82 22 04 4C 65 E2 CC 80 F2 23 F9 0C F3 09 30 CE 53 33 25 2F 9C 33 F4 53 31 BE 36 84 32 51 CB 49 83 11 43 E3 97 01 5A B1 26 6C 
    subject=/C=SG/O=Netrust Certificate Authority 1/OU=Netrust CA1 (Server)/OU=ABC/OU=ABC/CN=AAA
issuer=/C=SG/O=Netrust Certificate Authority 1/OU=Netrust CA1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<certificate details>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.3.92: 00 08 00 00 
    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.17.3.20: 1D 44 89 B2 45 26 7F 6F 6B 92 C5 3A 7B 72 63 CA D2 70 2A DD 
subject=/C=SG/O=Netrust Certificate Authority 1/OU=Netrust CA1
issuer=/C=SG/O=Netrust Certificate Authority 1/OU=Netrust CA1
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<certificate details>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```